# Loading pretrained model fast-bert

Tags: nlp, pytorch, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, fast-ai

This is my first time working on binary text classification, I'm working with CamemBert using  fast-bert library. After fine-tuning, I tried training but got this error :

```
Error(s) in loading state_dict for CamembertForSequenceClassification:
    size mismatch for classifier.out_proj.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([10, 768]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([2, 768]).
    size mismatch for classifier.out_proj.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([10]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([2]).
```

The weird thing is that I tried doing multi-label classification and it worked fine.

How can I fix this?

Here's the config.json file obtained after the fine-tuning:

```
{
  "architectures": [
    "CamembertForMultiLabelSequenceClassification"
  ],
  "attention_probs_dropout_prob": 0.1,
  "bos_token_id": 5,
  "eos_token_id": 6,
  "gradient_checkpointing": false,
  "hidden_act": "gelu",
  "hidden_dropout_prob": 0.1,
  "hidden_size": 768,
  "id2label": {
    "0": "LABEL_0",
    "1": "LABEL_1",
    "2": "LABEL_2",
    "3": "LABEL_3",
    "4": "LABEL_4",
    "5": "LABEL_5",
    "6": "LABEL_6",
    "7": "LABEL_7",
    "8": "LABEL_8",
    "9": "LABEL_9"
  },
  "initializer_range": 0.02,
  "intermediate_size": 3072,
  "label2id": {
    "LABEL_0": 0,
    "LABEL_1": 1,
    "LABEL_2": 2,
    "LABEL_3": 3,
    "LABEL_4": 4,
    "LABEL_5": 5,
    "LABEL_6": 6,
    "LABEL_7": 7,
    "LABEL_8": 8,
    "LABEL_9": 9
  },
  "layer_norm_eps": 1e-05,
  "max_position_embeddings": 514,
  "model_type": "camembert",
  "num_attention_heads": 12,
  "num_hidden_layers": 12,
  "output_past": true,
  "pad_token_id": 1,
  "type_vocab_size": 1,
  "vocab_size": 32005
}
```

Comment: You have probably saved a model which was able to predict 10 classes (i.e. you resized the output layer to 10). Now you try to load your model in the original class with just a 2 class output layer, but you need to load it in a class with a 10 class output layer. In order to resolve it, you need to resize before you can load your model.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you have any idea on how i can resize ? I thought setting multi_label on False would work.

Comment: What is inside the directory which contains your model? Does it have a config.json? Please add the config.json directly to your question.

Comment: I use the folder model_out obtained after fine-tuning my model.  I just checked my config.json file and you're right it does indeed try to predict 10 classes

Comment: I'm still trying to, but I will if I do.

Comment: I would love to but I don't have enough reputation to talk in the chat.

Comment: I don't load it myself, I am using the fast-bert library.

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1q92ysuN7sDYRLSQzyEbs8WTqu3Juj5hX?usp=sharing

Comment: I assume that the output of `dataBunch.labels` is 2?

Comment: I just checked and it's ['pos', 'neg']

Comment: Okay, so your model inside `model_out` has 10 classes. `fast_bert` creates a model based on the number of labels of your dataset. So you can either use a different camembert model (how about the official one from huggingface?) or modify the code of fast_bert to ignore the number of labels from your dataset.

Comment: How can I use a different Camembert model ? I'm sorry this is my first time working on text classification

Comment: Just set `pretrained_path` to  `'camembert-base'` instead of `'/content/drive/My Drive/model/model_out'`

Comment: Okay, and that means letting go of the fine-tuning right ?

Comment: Yes. Your other model was finetuned for 10 classes. Another way would be adding 8 artifical labels to your data or to modify the state_dict with [upsample](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-resize-feature-maps/18545/4)(haven't tried that, but I think it is possible).

Comment: Okay ! thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hey, I tried using the official camembert from the huggingface, this time the learner is created but the fit method returns: RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (2) must match the size of tensor b (39) at non-singleton dimension 1

Comment: Can you please delete this question and create a new one? Which contains your code and the full stacktrace of your error message.

Comment: Done ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63244792/the-size-of-tensor-a-2-must-match-the-size-of-tensor-b-39-at-non-singleton-d